# lstlistoflistings formatting problem

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, listings

I'm using `\lstlistoflistings` to create list of listings. Everything generates well except for the formatting issue I have. I tried to fix it but don't have enough knowledge.

This is how the formatting issue looks like[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably loading `tocloft` and changing the space for numbers relative to figures; so it's just a matter of telling TeX to treat listing captions like figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,chngcntr,tocloft}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \counterwithin*{lstlisting}{section}
  \counterwithin*{lstlisting}{subsection}
  \counterwithin*{lstlisting}{subsubsection}
  \renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{%
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
      \thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}%
    \else
      \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
        \thesubsection.\arabic{lstlisting}%
      \else
        \thesubsubsection.\arabic{lstlisting}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2em}
\makeatletter
\let\l@lstlisting\l@figure
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\section{A section}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{section.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{subsection.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{subsection.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{subsubsection.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{subsection.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
\section{A section}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{section.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) defines `\l@lstlisting` to be

```
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{#1}{#2}}
```

The above macro determines the formatting to the ToC-related entry for every listing. The third argument (`2.3em`) is used to allocate the width of the numbering within the `\lstlistoflistings`. You can modify that to the desired length, as below (to `3.5em`, say):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{lstlisting}}}
\makeatletter
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.5em}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\lstlistoflistings
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={First listing}]
A
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```